# Automatizar a publicação de apps iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, appstore, itunes

Eu trabalho criando apps por demanda (para Android e iOS). Os apps tem as mesmas funcionalidades e só diferem no estilo, o qual é definido pelos clientes.

No caso do Android eu pude automatizar todo o processo de criação e submissão de apps para a play store. Através do Gradle e de linhas de comando executadas no prompt/terminal eu consigo gerar o .apk e submetê-lo na play store (Um script PHP faz tudo pra mim).

Existe alguma forma de fazer a mesma coisa no iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe um lib chamada [Fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane), que também funciona pra Android, na qual é possível automatizar as tarefas de publicação. Nesse [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/116065/fastlane-tutorial-getting-started) você encontra um tutorial, em inglês, de como configurá-la.

Comment: Excelente! Muito obrigado! Isso ajudou bastante!